# Redirecting to Lowercase URL and removing trailing slashes for SEO

Tags: urls, seo

I am working on a task where I need to make sure that all the requests are served through lowercase URL's in `Sitecore 8.2`.

I have seen few articles around getting in done through IIS rewrite but than it does break few of the Sitecore client scripts which are case sensitive as highlighted in the article below:

https://blog.coates.dk/2018/01/15/lower-casing-rewrite-rules-breaks-the-sitecore-client/

Removing trailing slashes from URL is sort of straight forward and can be achieved through rewrite rules:

https://sitecoreblog.patelyogesh.in/2015/08/remove-trailing-slash-from-sitecore-urls.html

Has anyone implemented redirecting to lowercase URL in Sitecore? Should I start looking at overriding the `HttpBeginRequest pipeline` instead of rewrite rules?

Answer (score 5):

Have you checked the configuration in LinkManager?

```
<linkManager defaultProvider="sitecore">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="sitecore" type="Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" addAspxExtension="false" alwaysIncludeServerUrl="false" encodeNames="true" languageEmbedding="asNeeded" languageLocation="filePath" lowercaseUrls="false" shortenUrls="true" useDisplayName="false" />
  </providers>
</linkManager>
```

Try setting **lowercaseUrls="true"** through a config patch.

Comment: But this will not redirect the users to lowercase URL's. This will only ensure that sitecore generates the lowercase URL's through link manager.

Comment: "This will only ensure that sitecore generates the lowercase URL's through link manager" - Is all you need for purposes of SEO. If you want to go a step further and redirect uses who have manually typed in domain.com/ABC page to domain.com/abc , you need a IIS redirect rule